# obtener datos de Firebase y colocarlos en RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estoy obteniendo los datos de Firebase, ya que he debugeado y en el getValue aparecen los datos sin problema alguno, pero cuando quiero asignarselo a casas, los campos son null

**Este es el codigo principal donde obtengo los datos desde Firebase y los intento agregar a un adaptador**

```
   myDatabase.getRoot().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           casasList.removeAll(casasList);
           for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               Casas casas = childSnapshot.getValue(Casas.class);
               casasList.add(casas);
           }
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
```

**Tambien agrego la clase Casas donde tienen sus constructores y sus metodos getters and setters**
public class Casas {
    String correo,venta,compra,direccion,id;

```
public Casas(String correo, String venta, String compra, String direccion) {
    this.correo = correo;
    this.venta = venta;
    this.compra = compra;
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public Casas() {

}

public String getCorreo() {
    return correo;
}

public void setCorreo(String correo) {
    this.correo = correo;
}

public String getVenta() {
    return venta;
}

public void setVenta(String venta) {
    this.venta = venta;
}

public String getCompra() {
    return compra;
}

public void setCompra(String compra) {
    this.compra = compra;
}

public String getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}
```

}

**Esta es la clase donde construyo mi adaptador**

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

```
ArrayList<Casas> casasList;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Casas> casasList) {
    this.casasList = casasList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_casadecambio,parent,false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Casas casa = casasList.get(position);
    holder.compra.setText(casa.getCompra());
    holder.venta.setText(casa.getVenta());
    holder.direccion.setText(casa.getDireccion());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return casasList.size();
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué limpias la lista aquí: `casasList.removeAll(casasList);`? Prueba a comentar esa línea. Y haz una depuración de `casa` dentro del `for` para revisar si te está llenando la clase correctamente. Verifica también que estás obteniendo en cada caso un objeto que es mappeable a la clase `Casas`.

Comment: uso el removeAll para que no se repitan cuando haya una nueva actualizacion en la base de datos, no le afecta en nada ya que cuando hago la linea casasList.add(casas); casas esta vacia todos sus campos son null

Comment: Haz una depuración de `childSnapshot.getValue` dentro del `for`. Muestra el resultado en el `logcat` y di lo que imprime.